# Filling a hand object in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to fill a "hand" object in `matlab` using `imfill`. The object wasn't connected at the bottom so I drew a line and saved it. Now the object is completed and I'm trying to fill it using `imfill( ,'holes');` but it isn't working. Please someone help me out here....

This is the image :

[image]

And my code:

```
I = imread('45Hand.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(I);
[junk threshold] = edge(im, 'sobel');
fudgeFactor = 2;
BWs = edge(im,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
%figure, imshow(BWs), title('binary');
se90 = strel('line', 3, 90);
se0 = strel('line', 3, 0);
BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90 se0]);
figure, imshow(BWsdil), title('dilated gradient mask');
hold on
p1=[700,100];
p2=[700,1200];
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','w','LineWidth',4);

f = getframe(gca);
BWsdil = frame2im(f);

imwrite(BWsdil, 'image2.jpg');
img = imread('image2.jpg');
figure, imshow(img);
BWdfill = imfill(img, 'holes');
figure, imshow(BWdfill);
```

Comment: Be more explicit with what doesn't work? Simply saying it doesn't isn't very descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and if there is a problem with the line adjustment then set it back to [700,100] and [700,1200]
 `#I have changed it to some different value. (see code)`

```
I = imread('45Hand.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(I);
[h,w]=size(im);
[junk,threshold] = edge(im, 'sobel');
fudgeFactor = 2;
BWs = edge(im,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
%figure, imshow(BWs), title('binary');
se90 = strel('line', 3, 90);
se0 = strel('line', 3, 0);
BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90 se0]);
figure, imshow(BWsdil), title('dilated gradient mask');
hold on
p1=[h,0]; %  To draw a line on the bottom edge.
p2=[h,w];
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','w','LineWidth',4);

f = getframe(gca);
BWsdil = frame2im(f);

imwrite(BWsdil, 'image2.jpg');
img = imread('image2.jpg');
img = im2bw(img, graythresh(img));

figure, imshow(img);
BWdfill = imfill(img, 'holes');
figure, imshow(BWdfill);
```

this way you get filled hand part....

Problem was that you were trying to use `imfill(bw)` on `grayscale` images but it works on binary images... see [doc here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imfill.html)

Now the output image looks like:
[image: filled hand]

Comment: Thank you that worked fine.. :) but for the same coordinates, we get different lines in different images and different PCs... So is there any way I can join bottom two points so that I can fill or can I get line bottom line that is constant for every image..??